# ASP.NET Membership ChangePassword, UpdateUser lost update anomoly

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, asp.net-membership, change-password

I've found what I think is a pretty annoying issue with MembershipProvider... I'm hoping somebody else has already encountered this and solved it elegantly.

I've created a method which calculates password strength while changing the password so that I can store it for administrative purposes (auditing, forced resets, etc.) As I don't want to store plain-text passwords, this value needs to be calculated during the password change.

To make things worse, I'm making this improvement to an existing codebase, attempting not to touch a particular project, favouring minor config changes where possible. The code which calls my membership provider calls in this order:

GetUser
ChangePassword
UpdateUser

Unfortunately, calling UpdateUser after ChangePassword causes a lost update anomoly. To me, this seems like a fundamental flaw in the provider structure. ChangePassword is required to validate the password, but UpdateUser has no way of knowing which changes were made.

Has anybody else run into this issue?

Note: I understand that I can separate out the change password workflow and avoid UpdateUser entirely. I'm trying not to do this as it will require me to completely replace an existing block of code which might be updated in future versions of the existing code-base.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by deriving a new MembershipUser and overriding ChangePassword there, which calls ChangePassword in its base call.

I called the base method, and if the result was true, built my password 'metadata' into the object there. When the update method was called afterwords, the correct data was present on the object.

I'll leave this question open for a while in case somebody arrives at a better solution.